# How to fix "Cannot read property 'x' of undefined"?

Tags: reactjs, redux

I am new to development with react and redux and by now I would say I have some understanding of how everything is connected. I also try to fix as many things on my own as possible, but today I encountered an error which I cannot fix on my own.

#### Here is my component

It is connected correctly to my redux store and also the actions get dispatched and return data flawlessly.

```
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux';
import * as matchActions from '../actions/matchActions';

/**
 * 
 */
class Match extends React.Component {

    componentDidMount() {
        this.props.actions.fetchMatch(this.props.match.params.matchid);
    }

    /**
     * Renders the component.
     */
    render() {
        return (
            <React.Fragment>

            </React.Fragment>
        )
    }
}

/**
 * Exposes a part of the redux store to this component.
 * 
 * @param {*} reduxStore The entire redux store.
 * @param {*} ownProps The properties which are being passed down from the parent component.
 */
const mapStateToProps = (reduxStore, ownProps) => {
    console.log('data => ', reduxStore.matchReducer.match.all_word_counts); // this one works
    console.log('data => ', reduxStore.matchReducer.match.all_word_counts.gg); // this one fails

    return {
        matchData: reduxStore.matchReducer.match
    }
}

/**
 * Exposes the necessary actions actions to this component.
 * 
 * @param { function } dispatch This function executes the called actions.
 */
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
    return {
        actions: bindActionCreators(matchActions, dispatch)
    }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Match);
```

When I try to `console.log(reduxStore.matchReducer.match.all_word_counts)`, everything works fine and the object gets printed out.

See this screenshot

[image: See this screenshot]

As you can tell, there is a property called `gg`. When I try to print that, I get an error saying that `all_word_counts` is undefined.

See this screenshot

[image: See this screenshot]

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong? Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Where you are accessing `gg` in code?

Comment: There is a `console.log` in my `mapStateToProps` function. I am trying to access it there. (I'll add it to the code)

Comment: Just a guess, the object `reduxStore.matchReducer` is getting filled with data after some dispatches and you are trying to access it before the object gets the data? Can you try like, `if(reduxStore.matchReducer.match.all_word_counts)console.log('data => ', reduxStore.matchReducer.match.all_word_counts.gg);`

Comment: I have updated my question once more. Even if I place them right one after eachother, the one with the `.gg` fails. The data is definately there.

Comment: I would guess that this is called at least once before `all_word_counts` is defined. You are not showing the whole output of your app.

Comment: When executing my code, I get `data => undefined` twice and then the errormessages provided in the second screenshot. Do you need any more informations? @Sulthan

Comment: @MarkoMaric Well, then your log says everything you need to know `all_word_counts` really is undefined, which should not happen in the first place. Shouldn't you provide default data in your reducer? e.g. `{}`? Or should you not render that component if there are no data for it?

Comment: I might be missing your point here, but if there are two `console.log`s in a row which output the same object (the second one outputs a property of the object form the first `console.log`) shouldn't both of them not work? It only crashes if I add the second log. Just the first one works fine. @Sulthan

Comment: You said that you got `data => undefined` in your log. `mapStateToProps` is called several times and the first time `all_word_counts` is `undefined` which your console logs prove. Therefore you cannot access a property on it because it would crash. Where is the problem?

Comment: I seem to understand now. When I add a check if the `all_word_counts` is empty it works. I'll have to take a look at it a little better. It works now!